# add character in a regex match notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this text:

```
01 music 
02 soccer 
03 theater
```

I want to convert to

```
01;music
02;soccer 
03;theater
```

I got match with ^\d{2} regex, but i do not know replace this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capture group, and then in the replacement string reference the group again:

```
Find: "^(\d{2}) "
Replace: "$1;"
```

Or, use a look-behind:

```
Find: "(?<=^\d{2}) "
Replace: ";"
```

Answer (score 2):

How about find a `space` and replace with `;`?

No need for regular expression here.

Comment: that is just a example, i will using this in others ways, tks

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace `(\d{2})`  (do note that there is a space after the closing bracket) with `$1;`. The regular expression captures the number so you can use it in the replacement as `$1`.

Comment: This will result in `03; theater` since you're not removing the space.

Comment: Actually, I am; there is a space between the closing bracket and the backtick that closes the regex; unfortunately, you can barely see it, so... well caught.

Comment: Ah, right, so there is. Can you replace that space with `\s` so it's more obvious?

Comment: I added a note to explain the space, since `\s` could also catch other patterns that the OP isn't looking for.

Comment: You need to use `<code> </code>` to also highlight a space in the code.

Answer (score 0):

FindWhat: `(\d{2})(\s)`
Replace: `$1;`

In search mode select Regular Expresion

Comment: You don't need the brackets around `\s`.